# execlp system call not printing to standard output?

Tags: c++, system-calls

I am using execlp to run a wc command, using a file as an extra parameter to read the word count. This unix command:

```
wc -l HelloWorld.class
```

gives an output of : 7 HelloWorld.class

But in my C++ code where I use execlp, this line of code:

```
int rc2 = execlp("/bin/wc", "wc", "-l", "HelloWorld.class",  (char *) 0);
```

doesn't appear to work (it is blank).

I am only running that one line of code, and I get a blank output from it. The directory of the c++ files is the same as where I execute the unix command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it has no bearing on your specific problem but it doesn't mean much to count the lines in a `.class` file. You probably want to do it on the `.java` file or some other text file.

For your specific problem, you should first check that `/bin/wc` is the correct path for that executable. On my system (Debian), it's `/usr/bin/wc`.

Since `execlp` duplicates the path search functionality anyway (if it doesn't contain a `/` character), you could probably just use:

```
int rc2 = execlp ("wc", "wc", "-l", "HelloWorld.class",  (char *) 0);
```

If you want to check the path, use something like `which wc` from the shell, that should let you know where the actual executable is.

Comment: Thank you, that was my issue. I was assuming it was in /bin/wc as that was the path for the ls command which I was using earlier. thanks.